# Problem 6.3 from David Morin (classical mechanics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, reference-frames, oscillators

[image]

I get the lagrangian for the system as
$$
\begin{align}
\mathscr{L} = \frac{m}{2}(\dot{x}^2 + l^2\dot{\theta}^2 + 2l\dot{x}\dot{\theta}\cos \theta) + mgl\cos\theta
\end{align}
$$
Where $\theta$ is the angle that the stick makes with the vertical.

Since $\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial x} = 0$, $\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial \dot{x}} = m(\dot{x} + l\dot{\theta}\cos\theta)$ must be conserved.

Let $\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial \dot{x}} = km$. We have
$$
\begin{align*}
\dot{x} + l\dot{\theta}\cos\theta &= k \\
\implies dx + l\cos\theta d\theta &= kdt \\
\implies \int_{A}^{x}dx \ + \int_{\theta_0}^\theta l\cos\theta d\theta &= \int_0^t kdt \\
\implies x-A + l\sin\theta - l\sin\theta_0 &= kt \\
\implies l\sin\theta &= kt + A + l\sin\theta_0 - A \cos(\omega t)
\end{align*}
$$

However, this is completely wrong. What mistakes have I made?

Comment: x is not generalized coordinate, x =x(t) , you have just one generalized coordinate which is $~\theta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the Euler-Lagrange's equations for a set of $\{q_1,\dots, q_n\}$ generalized coordinates are valid if the $n$ coordinates are independent from each other. The $x$ coordinate of your problem represents a constraint, and the only independent variable is $\theta$. In order to write the Euler-Lagrange's equations for $x$, you'd have to introduce a generalized constraint force, that is, a force that compels $x$ to move as $x(t)=A\cos(\omega t)$. So, to sumarize, it's ok to write
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial{\dot{\theta}}}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}=0$$
but, for the $x$ coordinate, we'd have
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial{\dot{x}}}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=Q_x$$
where $Q_x$ is the generelized constraint force and is related to the Lagrange multipliers. I hope this answer to be helpful!